# Restarting Java Application: exec didn't do it

Tags: java, process, restart

What I need to do is to launch a java app, and restart it if needed.

The implementation attached didn't do it.

```
StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();
cmd.append(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java ");
for (String jvmArg : ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()) {
    cmd.append(jvmArg + " ");
}
cmd.append("-cp ").append(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getClassPath()).append(" ");
cmd.append(Main.class.getName()).append(" ");
for (String arg : args) {
    cmd.append(arg).append(" ");
}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: When you say 'did not do it', what do you mean? What happens when you try running that code?

Comment: please attach the error what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The method `exec()` returns a `Process` on which you can call `waitFor()`. This will keep the old process alive until (all) new process(es) finish. 
I suspect that because you immediately call `System.exit(0);`, the newly run child process is killed along with the parent one.

Or you could create an infinite loop in command line script (if you want to restart each and every time your app terminates), which runs your app, in bash that would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    command_which_starts_your_app
    # when the command finishes, new iteration will restart your app
done
```

Then if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> you cancel the script and the app restarting. Or you could use the return value of your application and terminate e.g. if it is > 0.